# How could I add namespace to Resources folder on web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a new folder `Resources` where I add `Languages.resx` to create a multilanguage application. Now I'm trying use the tag `<pages>` to add the `namespaces` to this folder but it doesn't works. I'm trying to create it to avoid use `@using MyProject.Resources` at each Views, but I cannot make it works.

How could I do this ?

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>

    <!--<globalization/>-->
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"/>

    <!--languages-->
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyProject"/>
        <add namespace="MyProject.Resources"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

    <!--redireciona caso a sessao tenha expirado ou o usuario nao esteja autenticado-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" loginUrl="~/Home/Index" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>

    <!-- ativa o custom errors
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/NotFound">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPage/NotFound"/>
    </customErrors> -->    

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />    
  </system.web>
```

**Trying to use**

**Html**

```
<h1>@Language.Name</h1>
```

Comment: There are multiple _web.confg_ files in an mvc project. Did you make your changes to the web.config in a Views folder?

Comment: Which `Web.config`? - should be the one in the `Views` folder (under `<system.web.webPages.razor>`)

Comment: You both are alright. Now it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `namespace` needs to be added to the `web.congfig` file in the `/Views` folder of your app (in the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section)

```
 <configuration>
     ....
     <system.web.webPages.razor>
          ....
          <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
               <namespaces>
                   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                   ....
                   <add namespace="MyProject"/>
                   <add namespace="MyProject.Resources"/>
               </namespaces>
           </pages>
       </system.web.webPages.razor>
```